# Select category in the form using select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React app. In this app I have page with post( `title`, `category_id`, `description`, `image`)

But now on page with post I need create `form` which add **new post** in my local server. This form have input for `title`, `description`, `image` and  `category` I should to choose in the `select`. The list of categories I get from the local server using `fetch` and API method `GET`

I did something, but in some places I don't know what to write.

### What to write in some places instead `/*.....*/` in file SelectCategory.js?

#### response from serever(list of categories which I get in `const data`):

```
{"data":
[{"id":20,"title":"auto"},
{"id":21,"title":"sport"},
{"id":23,"title":"new"}
]}
```

#### SelectCategory.js:

```
const SelectCategory = () => {
    
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    selectCategory: ''
});
      
    useEffect(() => {
       fetchData(); 
     }, [/*.....*/]);
    
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const data = await api(`${listRoute}`, {
          method: 'GET',
         });
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: data.data,
         }));
    
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }

    const upadateSelectCategory = (/*.....*/) => {         
     setValue({
        ...value,
        selectCategory: /*.....*/,
    });
   };
    
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={upadateSelectCategory} value={value.selectCategory}>
          <option value="">-- Category --</option>
          {/*.....*/.map(item => <option key={/*.....*/}>{/*.....*/}</option>)}  
        </select> 
      </div>
  );
}
```

#### AddPost.js:

```
const AddImage = () => {
      
 // THERE SOME CODE
    
   return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef}>
          <input type="text" name="title"/>
          <SelectCategory />
          <input type="text" name="description"/>
          <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>

          <button type="submit">Add</button>
       </form>
   </div>
  );};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, your are fetching all the categories from a server.
I would change your code to the following:

```
const SelectCategory = () => {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('')
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
       fetchData(); 
     }, []);

    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const data = await api(`${listRoute}`, {
          method: 'GET',
         });
          setCategories(data.data.map(cat => cat.title)
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }

    const upadateSelectCategory = e => {         
     setCategory(e.target.value);
   };

    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={upadateSelectCategory} value={category}>
          <option value="">-- Category --</option>
          {categories.map(item => <option key={item}>{item}</option>)}  
        </select> 
      </div>
  );
}
```

useEffect will execute only once. We map the data to get all the titles of the categories.
the onChange on the select send an events, the event has a target - the select, which has a value.

Comment: thank you very much! I want to ask you another question. I need pass `id`category to my local server. But now I pass title category. That is, I need that in select be title, but to server pass `id`. How to implement it?

Comment: on the fetch data - remove the map function. Instead, when you map over categories do this: ```categories.map(item => <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.title}</option>)```